# AddToSet operation requires a target array field

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Trying to make use of Azure DocumentDB/CosmsoDB using the MongoDB driver.  I have learned that there are many limitations as the full set of features is not currently implemented.  I want to use aggregate functions, specifically $group, and .distinct but I don't think that is available yet.  As a work around, I am trying to maintain a separate "tracking" document to enable "distinct".  trying to update a document using $addToSet, but getting the following:

```
MongoError: Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing function. Exception = Error: AddToSet operation requires a target array field.\r\nStack trace: Error: AddToSet operation requires a target array field.\n   at arrayAddToSet (__.sys.commonUpdate.js:2907:25)\n   at handleUpdate (__.sys.commonUpdate.js:2649:29)\n   at processOneResult (__.sys.commonUpdate.js:2484:25)\n   at queryCallback (__.sys.commonUpdate.js:2461:21)\n   at Anonymous function (__.sys.commonUpdate.js:619:29)"]}
```

The update command i am using:

```
var usersDocument = collection.updateOne(
   { "type": "users" },
   { $addToSet: {users: "someone@gmail.com"} },
    function(err, count, status) {
        console.log("updateOne err: " + err)
        console.log("updateOne count: " + count)
        console.log("updateOne status: " + status)
    }
)
```

This seems to me to be a pretty straight-forward command, pulled from the mongo documentation and fields adjusted as needed.  Maybe I am missing something really basic?

My ultimate goal was to make sure that my code was portable as to be able to move it into a Mongo cluster, if I so desired (not be locked into Azure-specific).  To get started and not have to manage a multi-server cluster, Azure CosmosDB looked like a great jumpstart, but the limitations are maddening.

UPDATE:
Now that I have fixed my document and I actually have a field with an array, $addToSet is just replacing the value, rather than adding to the array. I'll create a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, something basic.  The error message was actually correct.  After inspecting the existing document:
I found:

```
{ "users": "[]" }
```

And changed it to:

```
{ "users": [] }
```

Now it is working.